# validation error not seen in template form using form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

validation error is not shown before also when i created form using form api i send error but is does not appear in html and now also when created User using UserCreationForm now also error not appered in html submitting this form without fillig single field.

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import signup
# Create your views here.
def sign_up(request):
    fm = signup()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fm = signup(request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid() :
            print('until this runs')
            fm.save()
        else:
            fm = signup()
            print(fm.errors)
    return render(request, 'at/signup.html', {'form': fm})
```

forms.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class signup(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','first_name','last_name','email']
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" >
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <form method="post"  novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}

           {{ fms.as_p }}
            <button class="text-center btn btn-primary" type="submit">SUB</button>

        </form>



  </div>

</body>




</html>
```

tried this html code also but no erros are seen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>user regisration</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% if messages %}
<ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
       <li>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <form action="" method='POST' novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for fm in form  %}
            {{fm.label_tag}} {{fm}} {{fm.errors|striptags}} <br> <br>
   {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value='submit'>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering fields manually, you are responsible for displaying the error messages.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages